# Mosquitto 2.X for yocto

Tags: yocto, mosquitto

I have inherited a device / code base / quality process that only allows deploying packages supported by yocto.  I'm exploring options for replacing RabbitMQ with mqtt on our devices, but several of the services in the code base require message headers so I would prefer to adopt mqttv5.  I see that mosquitto has finally released an mqttv5 server (mosquitto 2.x).  I'm new to yocto, so I'm curious what is the time frame for yocto to support mosquitto 2.X?  Is there a better place to ask this question, such as a yocto discussion community or mailing list?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say when the recipe will be updated but its no magic to adjust a recipe for a newer version by yourself:

- Get the last available recipe. In case of mosquitto its for [version 1.6.12](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/mosquitto/mosquitto_1.6.12.bb)
- Rename recipe to match the wanted version: `mosquitto_1.6.12.bb` => `mosquitto_2.0.3.bb` and move it to the correct layer
- Download the appropriate archive ([mosquitto-2.0.3.tar.gz](http://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-2.0.3.tar.gz))
- Determine the md5 and sha256 checksum of the archive and change them within the recipe (might also be needed for license file if that changed)
- bitbake

In most of the cases this is all but it might be needed to take some further changes because the dependencies of the new version are different or patch files are not compatible anymore.

Comment: Bake-your-own would require reworking the QA process, because the first step is to verify the QA approval of the yocto recipe so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Well you might try it anyway and if it works make a pull request to openemmbeded repo. So you might speed up that the recipe change is part of a release and on top help others who want to use the newest mosquitto version with yocto as well